# I'm trying to pass instance of class between actors, but compiler rejects it

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Akka documentation says that any object can be passed as a message, but in practice it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code.

This class is intended to receive a passenger object with an id

```
class BagScanActor extends Actor {`enter code here`
    def receive = {
        case Passenger => println("hello back at you")
        case _       => println("huh?")
    }
}
```

Here is the simple Passenger class

```
class Passenger(id: Int) {

}
```

And here is the main object

```
object Tsa {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val numLines: Int = 2;

        val system = ActorSystem("ScreenerSystem")
        val bagActor = system.actorOf(Props(new BagScanActor(numLines)), name = "bagscanactor")
        bagActor ! Passenger
    }
}
```

There is an error saying 'not found: value Passenger' and I can't seem to find any documentation that shows how to pass a class rather than a case object. Any help in how to pass objects that contain values would be wonderful! Thanks!

Comment: yiu can't just pass a class to the actor - you have to instantiate it (construct an object) - `bagActor ! new Passenger`; if you need to match a class - `case p: Passanger =>`

Comment: @dk14 Why can't you send a class to an actor? `bagActor ! classOf[Passenger]`

Comment: It's object (reflection) representing class - not class itself

Answer (score 2):

As written, you're pattern matching against an object named `Passenger`, which doesn't exist, hence the compiler error.

If you want to match against an *instance* of `Passenger`, you need to give it an identifier:

```
case p: Passenger =>
```